# Subbundle of hermitian vector bundle with connection

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the trivial bundle $M \times V$ where $M$ is a real manifold and where $V$ is a complex vector space with hermitian inner product. I can equip this trivial bundle with the trivial connection. Suppose I am interested in a subbundle, which I construct by making a (smooth) choice of subspace of $V$ for each point in $M$. Does this subbundle 'inherit' a connection from the original (trivial) connection on $M \times V$ in any natural way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sub-bundles of a Hermitian vector bundle always inherit a connection in a natural way. Let $\rho:E\to E'$ denote the orthogonal projection onto a sub-bundle $E'$. Then define a connection $\nabla$ on $E'$ by $\nabla s=\rho(ds)$, where the projection is extended to forms in the obvious way (using a local basis). Since the projection $\rho$ is a bundle morphism, you can verify that $\nabla$ is indeed a connection:

1. $\nabla(fs)=\rho(d(fs))=\rho(df\otimes s+fds)=df\otimes s+f\nabla s$
2. $\nabla_{fX}s=\rho(ds)(fX)=f\rho(ds)(X)=f\nabla_Xs$

Note: the same works when $E$ is a not necessarily trivial Hermitian vector bundle with connection, then one simply replace $d$ by the connection on $E$.